# What is the best way to run migrations or load a schema the first time docker-compose up is run?

Tags: database, docker, web-applications, docker-compose, database-schema

I have a compose setup with two containers, webapp and db. It would be nice if, on first run of  `docker-compose up`, the migrations/schema in the webapp container would be run. These migrations aren't straight sql, so I can't put them in the db init directory (and they can't be a `sh` script there either, as they need dependencies not installed on db).

Is there a best practice way to do this, or is it best to just run it as a separate command? Ideally I'd like `docker-compose up` to be the only command someone like a new dev would need to run to get the whole composition up and running locally, if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You could add another service which runs the containerized migrations against the db host and make it depend on the db service, and then simply run `docker-compose up -d migrate`:

```
services:
  db: <some db stuff>

  migrate:
    <build/run your migration against the db container>
    depends_on:
     - "db"
```

The services will run in the background, the migrate container will die off, and the db container will remain running with migrations applied.

Comment: interesting idea, spinning up a different short-lived service to do the migration. I like the encapsulation that gives, and it theoretically could be the same image as the web app service. However, It still isn't "first run only". Yes, a short shell script could fix this, but is there a more automatic way? Seems like this case would be common enough to have a preferred solution.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in way to specify to run a service only once besides scripting it out. Is your migration platform able to detect the version of the database and skip the migrations if it's up-to-date? This isn't a "run-only-once" solution, but it is idempotent. Is there a reason you need "run-only-once" other than avoiding running duplicate migrations?

Comment: Yeah, like you said, I don't have an idempotent migration platform. It doesn't detect the current version, it must be specified for upgrades. Nothing I can do about that, unfortunately. Other systems I've worked on also have a separate workflow if the database is brand new or not (rails has `db:setup` for new databases and `db:migrate` for existing databases - although some people incorrectly use  `db:migrate` for both, and it works fine in simple cases).